# How can I match array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, I want match this arrays and get results with **keys**.
Can I search in first array with second array keys or match diffrent way?

```
$boardLists = [
  [
    '_id' => 'a1a1a1',
    'name' => 'Board Name #1',
    'code' => 'B1'
  ],
  [
    '_id' => 'b2b2b2',
    'name' => 'Board Name #2',
    'code' => 'B2
  ]
];
```

and

```
$boards = [
  'a1a1a1',
  'b2b2b2',
  'c3c3c3'
];
```

My result with *array_intersect*:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "a1a1a1" }
```

My expected result if match 'a1a1a1':

```
[
  '_id' => 'a1a1a1',
  'name' => 'Board Name #1',
  'code' => 'B1'
],
```

Comment: add what is your expected result.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I added

Comment: basically you will have multi-dimentional array1 & another array1. you want compare that. return matching array with array2. is that correct

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy Yes, exactly.

Comment: boards has two matching a1a1a1 & b1b1b1 whereas you mentioned only one in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That I could understand you want to search in the first array according to what you have in the second array, so here is one example:

```
$boardLists = [
  [
    '_id' => 'a1a1a1',
    'name' => 'Board Name #1',
    'code' => 'B1'
  ],
    [
    '_id' => 'b2b2b2',
    'name' => 'Board Name #2',
    'code' => 'B2' 
  ]

];

$boards = [
  'a1a1a1',
  'b2b2b2',
  'c3c3c3'
];
$boardListIds = array_column($boardLists, '_id');

$results = [];
foreach ($boards as $board) {
  $find_key = array_search($board, $boardListIds);
  if($find_key !== false)
    $results[] = $find_key;
}

#printing the results
foreach ($results as $result) {
  print_r($boardLists[$result]);
}
```

There many ways to do it, this is just one. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to have the array index of your first array the _id. However with the way the array is setup currently you could do:

```
foreach($boards as $key1=>board){
    foreach($boardLists as $key2=>$boardList){
        if($boardList['_id']==$key1){
                echo $key1 . PUP_EOL;
                print_r($boardList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($boardLists  as $key=>$val):
    if(in_array($val['_id'],$boards))
    {
        $finalArray[] = $val2;
    }
endforeach;
```